# Using dashboard uploader instead of FTP

Tags: wordpress, ftp

Recently, I change my host server. that causing a problem. When I want upload a new theme or plugin instead of using dashboard uploader want me to enter FTP host and username and password, What I can do to come back to the previous uploader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these is because you using a shared server.
you can add these code to wp-config.php

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

for more information see the [WordPress Upgrade Constants](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_Upgrade_Constants)

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are experiencing is due to file permissions for the site.

While it's more secure in it's current form, it is less convenient for updating WordPress, uploading images, etc.

**First:**
Have you actually ENTERED the FTP credentials into WP and seen if it works? If you do this, WordPress remembers the credentials, so you should only have to do it one time.  This would be the best way to go, if possible.

**Then:**
What you can do is attempt to change the file permissions through FTP.  If that does not work, often you can access the files and try and change permissions through the host provider's cPanel.  If that does not work, then you will need to request the host provider changes the file permissions.

Through cPanel:

1. Go to "File Manager"
2. when prompted which directory to go to, go to your "Web Root" directory.
3. Navigate to the appropriate WP folders and give them permissions by right clicking on the folder icon, choosing Change Permissions".
4. Some recommended settings can be found here: [WordPress file permissions](http://underscorebleach.net/jotsheet/2006/10/wordpress-file-permissions)

Comment: I have access to cpanel, so What I can do?

Comment: I have changed premession of wp-content to 0777 but wordpress ask me FTP information on upload plugin and themes